# Java xml-parsing using Simple returns ??? instead of greek letters

Tags: java, xml-parsing, simple-framework

I am trying to get the values of  from the following xml, but the code i've written returns a bunch of question-marks instead of what it was supposed to return. I'm guessing it must be some encoding issue, but I haven't found anything about that yet on the web.

```
  <channel>
    <title>ΖΩΔΙΑ Προβλέψεις, 1 Σεπτεμβρίου 2012</title>
   </channel>
```

zodiaClass.java

```
public class zodiaClass {

    @Root(strict = false)
    public static class Example {

        @Path("channel")
        @Element
        private String title;

    }

    public static void main(String[] list) throws Exception {
        Persister persister = new Persister();
        File file = new File("example1/download.xml");
        Example example = persister.read(Example.class, file);


        System.out.println(example.title);
    }
}
```

output:

```
????? ??????????, 1 ??????????? 2012
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the issue is with the input, and not with the output? That is -- is it possible that you're printing this in a command-line environment that doesn't really support Greek? (What happens if you try `System.out.println("\u03B1")`? You *should* see a lowercase alpha.)

Comment: You are right! I got a "?" again. Is there a way to make the Eclipse IDE's console support Greek chars?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Had to change the encoding of the java file as well. Many thanks for the reply mate!

Comment: post it as an answer, so that I can mark it and you can get the credits for it btw

Comment: @Alex: this isn't a forum, don't put "solved" in your title if you've fixed the issue - post an answer explaining what the problem really was and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As requested, this is a translation of the above comment thread into the form of an answer.]

I suspect that the issue is with the output, rather than with the input. Not all command-line environments support Greek. To test this, you can try `System.out.println("\u03B1")`; if your command-line supports Greek, it should show up as α (lowercase alpha).

In one of your comments, you mention that you're using Eclipse. If it does turn out that the problem is with the output, then [a Google search for Eclipse console encoding](https://www.google.com/search?q=Eclipse+console+encoding) suggests that there are a number of different approaches that people have tried successfully — everything from [modifying the relevant Run Configuration within Eclipse](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/) to [editing `eclipse.ini` and the system encoding](http://paranoid-engineering.blogspot.com/2008/05/getting-unicode-output-in-eclipse.html).

**Update:** [not *really* an update, but I'm trying to maintain the illusion of a regular answer . . .] I see from your follow-up comment that you were able to change the console encoding by changing the encoding of the `*.java` file. Cool!